# CSS trying to get drop downs, but the menu keeps breaking the layout

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, grid, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to implement a drop down.

The page is here:

http://breteastman.com/

The tab is Pollution Prevention.

Basically what is happening is when you roll over "Pollution Prevention" you get the "Pollution Prevention" link to drop center, 10-20 px down with the nav elements inline.

I need the "Pollution Prevention" to remain the same where it is before you roll over and the drop down to go vertical.

This is a wordpress custom site. Pleas help!

Here is all of my CSS.

```
@import url('sidebar.css');


html, body {margin:0;padding:0;}

/* ***************** Body Styles ****************** */
html{
    background:url("images/background.jpg");
    font-family:arial;
}
body{
    background:url("images/contentArea.jpg") repeat-y;
    background-position:center;
    height:100%;
    font-family:arial;
}
#footer{
    text-align:center;
}
#header{
    background:url("images/header.jpg") no-repeat;
    height:284px;
}

/* padding top right bottom left; */
#newsArea > .grid_3 > p {padding:0 20px 0 20px;}
#newsArea > h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {padding-left:50px;}

/* ***************** Navigation ****************** */
.main{padding-top:2 0px;text-align:center;}
#menu-main-menu{margin-left:-30px;width:1092px;}
#menu-main-menu a:hover {color:pink;}
#menu-top-menu, #menu-main-menu{
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
}
    .main {
        margin-top:20px;
    }
    ul#menu-top-menu{
        margin-left:37px;
    }
        ul#menu-top-menu li a{
            font-size:1.1em;
        }
    #menu-top-menu li {
        display:inline;
    }
    #menu-main-menu li{
        float:left; 
    }
    #menu-top-menu li, #menu-main-menu li{
        padding-left:5px;
        padding-right:5px;
        border-right:1px #fff solid;
    }
    .main{
        padding-top:-1000px;
    }
    #menu-top-menu li{
        background:url("images/topNavBorderRight.jpg") no-repeat; 
        background-position:right top;
        border:0;
        /* padding top right bottom left; */
        padding: 23px 27px 30px 0px;
        max-width:40px;
        margin-left:-5px;
    }
    #menu-top-menu li a {padding-right:10px;}


        #menu-top-menu li a, #menu-main-menu li a{
            color:#fff;
            font-size:1.2em;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
            #navigation li a:hover{
                color:#399edb;
                text-decoration:none;
            }


/* dropdowns */ 

/* Hiding the other chlidren */ 

ul#menu-main-menu li#menu-item-64:hover ul.sub-menu {float:left;display:block;}
ul#menu-main-menu li#menu-item-64:hover ul.sub-menu li a {background-color:#000;padding:5px;color:#fff;}
/*ul#menu-main-menu li#menu-item-64:hover ul.sub-menu li {float:none;}
 ul#menu-main-menu li#menu-item-64:hover > ul.sub-menu li.menu-item > ul.sub-menu > * {display:none;} */ 



/* ***************** Slider Area ****************** */
#contentArea{
    background:url("images/sliderArea.png") no-repeat;
    height:349px;
}
/* ***************** Body Area ****************** */
#newsArea{
    background:url("images/newsArea.png") no-repeat;
    height:446px;
    padding-top:20px;
}
#newsArea h1 
{
    color:#00688f;
}
.overLayImages{
    position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:10;
}
.homeSlider{
    position:absolute;left:10px;top:15px;z-index:1;
}
.footer{
    margin-left:-35px;
    text-align:center;
    background:url("images/footerArea.jpg") no-repeat;
    width:1132px;
    height:290px;
}

/* 
    list-style: url("images/arrowIcon.png") inside;
*/
#contentArea *{color:#fff;}
#contentArea h1{text-align:left;padding-left:10px;text-transform:uppercase;}
#contentArea p{line-height:1.6em;padding-top:10px;padding-left:10px;}
#contentArea .details ul {line-height:2em;width:300px;list-style-type:none;}
/* padding top right bottom left; */
#contentArea .details ul li{background:url("images/arrowIcon.png") left center no-repeat;padding:10px 0px 10px 40px;}
#contentArea .details ul li:first-child {border-top:2px dotted #fff;}
#contentArea .details ul li {border-bottom:2px dotted #fff;font-size:1.2em;vertical-align:center;margin-bottom:10px;}

*{
    font-family:OfficSanBoo;
}

/* Sub pages */

    /* Default background */  
    #subpageImage {background:url("images/subpagePhoto/main.jpg") no-repeat;height:326px;}
    #subpageImage * {color:#fff;}
    #subpageImage ul li {display:inline;}
    #subpageImage .subText {height:290px;}

    /* tabs */ 

    ul#tabbedNavigation {background:url("images/tabbedNav/menuBG.jpg");float:right;margin-right:20px;padding:10px 0px 3px 0px;}
    /* padding top right bottom left; */
    ul#tabbedNavigation li {padding-top:11px;}
    ul#tabbedNavigation li {padding-bottom:33px;margin:0;background:url("images/tabbedNav/bgRight.jpg") no-repeat;background-position:right top;}
    ul#tabbedNavigation li a {padding-right:30px;}

    /* body styles */ 

    #bodyContent {background:url("images/bodyBackground.jpg") repeat-x;min-height:884px;}
    #bodyContent h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {padding:0;}
    .bodyContentPadding {padding:20px;}
    #bodyContent ol {width:520px;display:block;}
    #bodyContent ol li {display:inline;width:140px;display:block;}
    #sidebar {background:url("images/sidebarBG.jpg") repeat-x;height:884px;}
```

The jQuery

```
            $('#menu-main-menu li#menu-item-64').hover(
                function () {
                    //show its submenu
                    $('ul.sub-menu', this).slideDown(100);

                },
                function () {
                    //hide its submenu
                    $('ul.sub-menu', this).slideUp(100);        
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS seems to do it quite well. http://www.csspivot.com/iqNMK

```
.sub-menu { position: absolute; display: none; }
```

Of course it does shift some things around but im sure you can handle that.

Comment: How do I get each one on a new line>?

Comment: http://www.csspivot.com/2uCe6 I see this ( or something like this ) as the only proper solution as if you wanted to, you could force the submenu in one row while keeping it it its current position, but that would create extra scroll on the right side.

Comment: Reading isnt my thing.. thought you said "on one line" ..Well.. heres each li in a _new_ line http://www.csspivot.com/46Hlb

Comment: The drop down is working now. But it's now disappearing when I hover over. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you might have fixed that now, as i cant seem to get it to disappeappear while moving from the parent item to the child items.

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot test it on iPhone, I think this is a css position problem and/or z-index...